# UiTextField events

Tags: iphone, events, uitextfield

When I create UITextField inside Interface Builder, I can access Events tab for it, which has events like Value changed, Touch cancel, Touch drag, etc. I can assign my own methods to every of those events. How can I do the same, when I create UITextField programmatically with alloc?

Comment: Hi, I've created a UITextField in Interface Builder and want to register UIControlEventValueChanged. How do you go about it? How do you define that function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refer to Apple documentation for `UIControl`. After initializing your `textField`, call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`

example for the touch event ending an edit session

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchValueChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingDidEnd]
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you need to use UIControlEventEditingChanged

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `UIControlEventValueChanged`, you should use `UIControlEventEditingChanged`:

```
[_titleTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTitleValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Comment: from hajikelist's answer (belongs here as a comment instead of being an answer itself): UIControlEventEditingChanged fires whenever user changes value [synchronous with typing or keyup] which could cause extra hits to your data handler routine, if you're saving values based on that event, expecting it to be some kind of final value from user input...(you could end up with unexpected behavior, like having multiple saves for each textfield.)

Answer (score 3):

`UIControlEventEditingChanged` fires whenever user changes value [synchronous with typing or keyup] 
which could cause extra hits to your data handler routine, *if* you're saving values based on that event, expecting it to be some kind of final value from user input...

Comment: A good point, but should probably be a comment under one of the other answers instead of an answer itself, since you didn't specify an alternative to those answers.