# How to move slider when textfield has been changed?

Tags: ios, xcode, slider, textfield

Now, when I move the slider, the value of my textfield is changing. I need to that worked backwards also, whet change textfield value, slider moves.

My code:

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {

    self.slider.valueChangedHandler = ^(id sender) {
    self.aleField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [(UISlider *)sender value]];
};

}
```

**EDIT**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   slider.value = [aleField.text floatValue];

    NSUInteger newLength = [aleField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 2) ? NO : YES;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating your textfield, add:

```
[self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then have the following method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)sender {
    //Assuming slider is a property
    slider.value = [sender.text floatValue];
}
```

I referenced https://stackoverflow.com/a/7010676/391040 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4711136/391040.

Answer (score 2):

To do it while typing, implement the text field delegate

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *numberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:numberSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    BOOL basicTest = [string isEqualToString:filtered];
    if (basicTest) {
        slider.value = [aleField.text floatValue];
    }
    return basicTest;
}
```

This will also allow you to let the user insert only numbers.

To reflect the value to your slider:

```
slider.value = [textField.text floatValue];
```

Comment: When I enter for example number 3, it automatically puts a zero before 3

Comment: zero is a minimum value for slider.. if I put 1 for example, it puts 1 before number I enter

Comment: Nothing changed. When I put for example number 50.. slider moves to 5... when I put 99.. slider moves to 9... but if I put 999... then slider moves to 99.

Comment: You can add a dot to NSCharacterSet for float

Comment: It has nothing to do with your problem. You can add it if you want float values and not just integers.

Comment: My mistake, the textfield value in shouldChangeCharactersInRange will not be updated yet. So you will also need eitan27's method.

Comment: Yes! Now it works.. I accepted his method. Thank you for explanation!