# How to set UILabel's value according to UITextField as it is typed in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

I want to set UILabel according to the UITextField as it is typed. I mean if user want to type SAMPLE and he starts typing S then the lable should be set as S, then he types A label should also be A and so on. How to achieve this?

Please share suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any limit of text ???? Means in case of UILabel you will have to increase its size... It would be better if you show me your UI of that view ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way to do is to make a method and connect it with UiTextfield with event `UIControlEventEditingChanged` which will give you the trace on every character entered in the  textfield.

```
[self.selectedTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(enterInLabel ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


-(void)enterInLabel 
{ 
    selectedLabel.text=selectedTextField.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegate also works for this as @brain said. The `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method can be a little confusing but the the following I think is pretty straight forward.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

// myTextField delegate has been set

if ([textField isEqual:myTextField]){
    NSMutableString *txt = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
    [txt replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string]; //this is essentially how the textfield is updated after YES is returned
    previewLabel.text = txt;
}
return YES;
}
```

The changing of the text field is actually done after the return YES. That is the whole point of this delegate. Just for an example, if you wanted to limit a textfield to 3 characters you could do the following to stop the text field from "replacing" the text.

```
 if (range.location > 3) 
    return NO;
```

Answer (score -1):

Set your `textField` delegate then call its method in your `viewController.m` file.. like this -

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    mylabel.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    return YES;
}
```

This will change the text after each increment of character.

**OR You can add action on your TextField**
See this link - [UiTextField events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593976/uitextfield-events)

Comment: I have already tried this method. But this types 1 character late. I mean when user have to type SAMPLE and he starts typing S it remains blank then he types A it prints S in label and he types M then it prints A in label and so on. I need instant printing in label

Answer (score -2):

Your view controller will need to implement the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) which will allow it to receive changes to the text field. In the appropriate methods of the delegate you need to set the text of the UILabel.

I have never used UITextFieldDelegate so can't provide more detail on how to use it. I would mock up a quick example and just NSLog or debug the delegate calls to see that calls you get.

Comment: I know the delegate methods. If you know any sample code for it please provide that

Comment: This is wrong down voting... He has already said that he doesn't know the syntax ...but he gave a right way...you can handle you textField event with its delegates method....